# How does 'filecontents' keep LaTeX parsing while temporarily stop writing output

Tags: external-files, parsing

We all know `filecontents.sty` can do

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{document}

Hello World

\begin{filecontents}{dummy.txt}
No one will read this if I don't use it elsewhere
\end{filecontents}

\end{document}
```

But since the `filecontents.sty`'s code is pretty advanced chemistry, I do not get how it prevents including `No one will read this if I don't use it elsewhere`.

Comment: If you do `\immediate\write20{This won't go in the PDF file}`, the text won't appear in the PDF output, but only in the log file (and on the terminal). This is basically how `filecontents` works, it just uses a file stream for its output rather than the log file.

Comment: Clarification: I know how to do this with `\newcommand`, but struggle with defining an **environment** that reads its body without shipping out

Comment: See the `environ` package (at least if your goal is to collect the contents of the env in order to deal with it later).

Comment: @arney `filecontents` reads the contents line by line, stopping when it finds a line that starts with `\end{filecontents}`. It's just a different form of `verbatim`: instead of printing the line, `filecontents` sends it to the output file stream.

Comment: @egrep Yes, I know the tactic, but which commands do actually cause TeX to "change its stdout". I cannot see through all this plainTeX and multi-@-commands.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The basic working of the `filecontents` environment is the same as `verbatim`: every character is made printable and the end of line character is made active so that LaTeX can define it to delimit an argument which will be an entire line of input.

First the environment checks whether the named file already exists and, in this case, does nothing else than discarding everything up to `\end{filecontents}`. Otherwise it opens an output stream and writes some information lines (this is suppressed with `\begin{filecontents*}`.

Then it reads one line at a time as roughly explained above; if this line turns out to be `\end{filecontents}` (or `\end{filecontents*}` for the variant environment), the write stream is closed, otherwise the line is written to the output file.

A possible more efficient strategy is outlined in the documentation of the `verbatim` package, where the definition of a possible `verbatimwrite` environment is shown. I used the same in my `abc` package.

Comment: Sorry for the offtopic question, but is it possible to store some data inside a macro instead of a physical file? For example, can I have something like `\begin{filecontents*}{\mydata}` instead of `\begin{filecontents*}{mydata.dat}`?

Comment: @Diaa Perhaps have a try on the `filecontentsdef` package that seems to do what you are looking for (not tested, as I use my own more involved version)