# Is possible to remove the link color of the comma on the citation link?

Tags: biblatex, hyperref, links, abnt

Running this example:

```
% How does 'filecontents' keep LaTeX parsing while temporarily stop writing output
% https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/104159/how-does-filecontents-keep-latex
\RequirePackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents*}{references.bib}
@book{koma-scrguien,
  author = {Markus Kohm},
  edition = {2017-04-13},
  howpublished = {\url{http://mirrors.ibiblio.org/CTAN/.../scrguien.pdf}},
  publisher = {Online Material; \url{https://www.ctan.org/pkg/koma-script}},
  title = {The Guide KOMA -Script},
  urlaccessdate = {2017-08-28},
  year = {2017}
}
\end{filecontents*}

\PassOptionsToPackage{brazil,main=english}{babel}
\documentclass[
10pt,
a5paper,
twoside
chapter=TITLE,
section=TITLE
]{abntex2}
\pdfstringdefDisableCommands{\let\uppercase\relax}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage[
style=abnt,
language=english,
backref=true,
backend=biber,
citecounter=true
]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{references.bib}

\usepackage{csquotes}
\hypersetup{colorlinks=true}

\begin{document}

    Citing \cite[p. 47-52 and 135]{koma-scrguien}

    \printbibliography

\end{document}
```

We got the following output:

[image]

Where the comma between `KOHM` and `2017` is also green. Is possible to change its color to black, like in this montage bellow?

[image]

---

Related:

1. [Biblatex, authoryear-comp, and hyperlinks](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/27607/biblatex-authoryear-comp-and-hyperlinks)
2. [Single link in (Author, Year) citation style using natbib and hyperref](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/115039/single-link-in-author-year-citation-style-using-natbib-and-hyperref)
3. [natbib and hyperref for (Author, Year) style produces two links](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/24136/natbib-and-hyperref-for-author-year-style-produces-two-links)

Comment: The whole “KOHM, 2017” is the link. I guess one could make two distinct links.

Comment: Personally, I would not do that, as that would technically and visually make it two links, which confuses the reader. As it is, the comma's just part of the one link (like @egreg already said). With the comma in black, I as a reader would definitely wonder whether the year's a second link.

Comment: It would be better to have ``KOHM 2017`` with no comma then if that is supposed to be a single link.

Comment: Interesting! You are the first person to ask for a link to be split, normally people want more parts of the citation label to be linked in the standard styles and insist on a continuous link (and colouring). Your style explicitly links the entire label. May I ask why you want this.

Comment: @moewe, thanks for the fix! I did not liked coloring only the first comma `,` as the immediate second comma `,` is not colored. It also creates the impression of two distinct links, but I think it is nicer to have the coloring symmetry other the double link impression. We could think about coloring the second comma also `,` but extending a link into the remaining part would make it wrong as the reader would think the link is going to open the `p. 47-52 and 135`, which is not true.

Comment: Exactly, this is why the second comma (the one before the page number) is not coloured.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`abnt.cbx` contains the lines

```
\savebibmacro{cite}%

\renewbibmacro*{cite}{%% >>>2
  \printtext[citehyperref]{%
    \restorebibmacro{cite}%
    \usebibmacro{cite}}%
}% <<<2
```

This effectively wraps the entire output of `cite` into `citehyperref`, so that all of it linked.

If we do

```
\DeclareFieldFormat{citehyperref}{#1}
```

this undoes the lines from above so that they don't have an effect any more. Since most parts of `cite` still use `bibhyperref` quite extensively, you retain exactly the links you want.

```
\PassOptionsToPackage{brazil,main=english}{babel}
\documentclass[
10pt,
a5paper,
twoside
chapter=TITLE,
section=TITLE
]{abntex2}
\pdfstringdefDisableCommands{\let\uppercase\relax}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage[
style=abnt,
language=english,
backref=true,
backend=biber,
citecounter=true
]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\usepackage{csquotes}
\hypersetup{colorlinks=true}

\DeclareFieldFormat{citehyperref}{#1}

\begin{document}
  Citing \cite[\ppno~47-52 and 135]{nussbaum}

  \printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: citation with non-linked comma between labelname and labelyear]